Github Actions and Local Rust Out of Sync
My github actions appear to be running a different versions or configurations for rustfmt, or some similar issue.
How do I bring my CI (Github action runner) and my local environment into parity?
The problem:
cargo fmt --check and cargo fmt produces no output locally and does flag issues on the Github actions environemnt.
There is no rustfmt.toml in the repo nor a ~/.config/rustfmt/rustfmt.toml.
My Local computer (MacOS M1):
> cargo fmt --check  
# NO OUTPUT

> rustc --version
rustc 1.82.0 (f6e511eec 2024-10-15)

> cargo --version
cargo 1.82.0 (8f40fc59f 2024-08-21)

> rustfmt --version
rustfmt 1.7.1-stable (f6e511ee 2024-10-15)

> rustup show
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/casey/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-2022-12-12-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2023-04-16-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2023-08-24-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2024-01-16-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2024-02-06-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2024-07-18-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin
1.67-aarch64-apple-darwin
risc0

active toolchain
----------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.82.0 (f6e511eec 2024-10-15)

Github action output:
Log Rust version:
Run rustc --version
rustc 1.82.0 (f6e511eec 2024-10-15)

Log Cargo version:
Run cargo --version
cargo 1.82.0 (8f40fc59f 2024-08-21)

Log rustfmt version:
Run rustfmt --version
rustfmt 1.7.1-stable (f6e511e 2024-10-15)

Log rustup toolchain info:
0s
Run rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/runner/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
1.82.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

1.82.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (directory override for '/home/runner/work/zero2prod/zero2prod')
rustc 1.82.0 (f6e511eec 2024-10-15)

Enforce formatting:
Run cargo fmt --check
 cargo fmt --check
 shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
 env:
    CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always
    SQLX_VERSION: 0.8.0
    SQLX_FEATURES: rustls,postgres
    APP_USER: app
    APP_USER_PWD: secret
    APP_DB_NAME: newsletter
    CARGO_INCREMENTAL: 0
    CARGO_PROFILE_DEV_DEBUG: 0
    RUST_BACKTRACE: short
    RUSTFLAGS: -D warnings
    CARGO_UNSTABLE_SPARSE_REGISTRY: true
    CARGO_REGISTRIES_CRATES_IO_PROTOCOL: sparse
    CACHE_ON_FAILURE: true
Warning: Diff in /home/runner/work/zero2prod/zero2prod/src/routes/subscriptions.rs:1:
 use actix_web::{web, HttpResponse};
-use sqlx::PgPool;
 use chrono::Utc;
+use sqlx::PgPool;
 use uuid::Uuid;
 
 #[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
Warning: Diff in /home/runner/work/zero2prod/zero2prod/src/telemetry.rs:2:
 use tracing::Subscriber;
 use tracing_bunyan_formatter::{BunyanFormattingLayer, JsonStorageLayer};
 use tracing_log::LogTracer;
-use tracing_subscriber::{layer::SubscriberExt, EnvFilter, Registry};
 use tracing_subscriber::fmt::MakeWriter;
+use tracing_subscriber::{layer::SubscriberExt, EnvFilter, Registry};
 
 pub fn get_subscriber<Sink>(
     name: String,
Warning: Diff in /home/runner/work/zero2prod/zero2prod/src/main.rs:1:
 use secrecy::ExposeSecret;
+use sqlx::postgres::{PgPool, PgPoolOptions};
+use std::net::TcpListener;
 use zero2prod::configuration::get_configuration;
 use zero2prod::startup::run;
 use zero2prod::telemetry::{get_subscriber, init_subscriber};
Warning: Diff in /home/runner/work/zero2prod/zero2prod/src/main.rs:5:
-use sqlx::postgres::{PgPool, PgPoolOptions};
-use std::net::TcpListener;
 
 #[tokio::main]
 async fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
Warning: Diff in /home/runner/work/zero2prod/zero2prod/tests/health_check.rs:1:
-use zero2prod::configuration::{get_configuration, DatabaseSettings};
-use zero2prod::startup::run;
-use zero2prod::telemetry::{get_subscriber, init_subscriber};
+use secrecy::Secret;
 use sqlx::{Connection, Executor, PgConnection, PgPool};
 use std::net::TcpListener;
-use uuid::Uuid;
 use std::sync::LazyLock;
-use secrecy::Secret;
+use uuid::Uuid;
+use zero2prod::configuration::{get_configuration, DatabaseSettings};
+use zero2prod::startup::run;
+use zero2prod::telemetry::{get_subscriber, init_subscriber};
 
 pub struct TestApp {
     pub address: String,
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

My repo:
.github/workflows/general.yml, I added the aforementioned env logging and with: toolchain: 1.82.0 (in two places) as compared to the general.yml from the repo / book I'm follow (Zero to Production in Rust)
name: Rust

on:
  # NB: this differs from the book's project!
  # These settings allow us to run this specific CI pipeline for PRs against
  # this specific branch (a.k.a. book chapter).
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
    branches:
      - main

env:
  CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always
  SQLX_VERSION: 0.8.0
  SQLX_FEATURES: "rustls,postgres"
  APP_USER: app
  APP_USER_PWD: secret
  APP_DB_NAME: newsletter

jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Service containers to run alongside the `test` container job
    services:
      postgres:
        # Docker Hub image
        image: postgres:14
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
          POSTGRES_DB: postgres
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
    steps:
      # Downloads a copy of the code in your repository before running CI tests
      - name: Check out repository code
        # The uses keyword specifies that this step will run v4 of the actions/checkout action.
        # This is an action that checks out your repository onto the runner, allowing you to run scripts or other actions against your code (such as build and test tools).
        # You should use the checkout action any time your workflow will run against the repository's code.
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      # This GitHub Action installs a Rust toolchain using rustup. It is designed for one-line concise usage and good defaults.
      # It also takes care of caching intermediate build artifacts.
      - name: Install the Rust toolchain
        uses: actions-rust-lang/setup-rust-toolchain@v1
        with:
          toolchain: 1.82.0  # Ensure the toolchain matches your local version
          components: rustfmt

      - name: Log Rust version
        run: rustc --version

      - name: Log rustup toolchain info
        run: rustup show

      - name: Install sqlx-cli
        run:
          cargo install sqlx-cli
          --version=${{ env.SQLX_VERSION }}
          --features ${{ env.SQLX_FEATURES }}
          --no-default-features
          --locked
          # The --locked flag can be used to force Cargo to use the packaged Cargo.lock file if it is available.
          # This may be useful for ensuring reproducible builds, to use the exact same set of dependencies that were available when the package was published.
          # It may also be useful if a newer version of a dependency is published that no longer builds on your system, or has other problems

      - name: Create app user in Postgres
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install postgresql-client

          # Create the application user
          CREATE_QUERY="CREATE USER ${APP_USER} WITH PASSWORD '${APP_USER_PWD}';"
          PGPASSWORD="password" psql -U "postgres" -h "localhost" -c "${CREATE_QUERY}"

          # Grant create db privileges to the app user
          GRANT_QUERY="ALTER USER ${APP_USER} CREATEDB;"
          PGPASSWORD="password" psql -U "postgres" -h "localhost" -c "${GRANT_QUERY}"

      - name: Migrate database
        run: |
          SKIP_DOCKER=true ./scripts/init_db.sh

      - name: Run tests
        run: cargo test

      - name: Check that queries are fresh
        run: cargo sqlx prepare --workspace --check -- --all-targets

  # `fmt` container job
  fmt:
    name: Rustfmt
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Install the Rust toolchain
        uses: actions-rust-lang/setup-rust-toolchain@v1
        with:
          toolchain: 1.82.0
          components: rustfmt

      - name: Log Rust version
        run: rustc --version

      - name: Log rustup toolchain info
        run: rustup show

      # - name: Apply formatting
      #   run: cargo fmt
      - name: Enforce formatting
        run: cargo fmt --check

  clippy:
    name: Clippy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      SQLX_OFFLINE: true
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Install the Rust toolchain
        uses: actions-rust-lang/setup-rust-toolchain@v1
        with:
          components: clippy
      - name: Linting
        run: cargo clippy -- -D warnings

  coverage:
    name: Code coverage
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:14
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
          POSTGRES_DB: postgres
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Install the Rust toolchain
        uses: actions-rust-lang/setup-rust-toolchain@v1
        with:
          components: llvm-tools-preview
      - name: Install sqlx-cli
        run: cargo install sqlx-cli
          --version=${{ env.SQLX_VERSION }}
          --features ${{ env.SQLX_FEATURES }}
          --no-default-features
          --locked
      - name: Create app user in Postgres
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install postgresql-client

          # Create the application user
          CREATE_QUERY="CREATE USER ${APP_USER} WITH PASSWORD '${APP_USER_PWD}';"
          PGPASSWORD="password" psql -U "postgres" -h "localhost" -c "${CREATE_QUERY}"

          # Grant create db privileges to the app user
          GRANT_QUERY="ALTER USER ${APP_USER} CREATEDB;"
          PGPASSWORD="password" psql -U "postgres" -h "localhost" -c "${GRANT_QUERY}"
      - name: Migrate database
        run: SKIP_DOCKER=true ./scripts/init_db.sh
      - name: Install cargo-llvm-cov
        uses: taiki-e/install-action@cargo-llvm-cov
      - name: Generate code coverage
        run: cargo llvm-cov --all-features --workspace --lcov --output-path lcov.info
      - name: Generate report
        run: cargo llvm-cov report --html --output-dir coverage
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: "Coverage report"
          path: coverage/

.cargo/config.toml:
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
rustflags = ["-C", "linker=clang", "-C", "link-arg=-fuse-ld=lld"]

[target.x86_64-pc-windows-msvc]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=-fuse-ld=lld"]

[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=-fuse-ld=lld"]

[target.x86_64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=-fuse-ld=lld"]

[target.aarch64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=-fuse-ld=lld"]

